# Как провести несколько преобразований текста поля в mysql перед поиском?

Tags: mysql

Есть база писем. Нужно чтобы в ней произошел поиск куска текста скажем в 400 символов притом пробелы и слова <4х символов не учитываются.

Тоесть мне нужно выбрать все записи где колонка с текстом включает в себя искомый текст , но при этом без учета пробелов и слов <4x .Если входную строку я могу средствами php обрабоать , то как мне подготовить поле в базе ??

SELECT * FROM `user_messages` WHERE `message` like "%текст без пробелов и менше 4х пришедший с php%"

вот как в message тоже вырезать пробелы и маленкие слова? Изменять само поле messages в базе не нужно.

Comment: mysql не может так просто работать с текстом. Из вариантов: 1. полнотекстовый поиск (в гугле в вбейте эту фразу и mysql). 2. вместо like писать regexp из вашего поискового текса создавать регулярное выражение, могущее пропускать короткие слова. 3. Писать хранимую функцию mysql которая сделает необхомое с текстом. 4. заранее подготовить текст без коротких слов или вообще словарь и id слов к сообщению. Из нормальных по скорости только 1й и возможно 4й при грамотном подходе

Comment: Только как в полнотекстовом поиске опять же исключить пробелы и слова меньше 4х ?

Comment: Полнотекстовый поиск по крайней мере даст вам письма где эти слова встречаются и по уровню релевантности будет ясно на сколько близко совпадение. А потом, при желании убедится в точном соответствии за исключением коротких слов дальнейшую обработку провести на php

Comment: Спасибо. Еще бы понять как эту релевантность сделать в нормальных процентах. Например я беру весь текст  из одного поля базы (слова русские но utf8) и ищу.Нашло все,но в том поле где она 100% совпадает - мне пишет релевантность 15% ,а должно быть 100